# This eventmachine code serves only one client and only once

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, eventmachine

I'm a complete newbie in this & I made a simple code that fetches data from RabbitMQ and sends it to client connected via websockets.

Problem here is:

- if I start a app and a client connects (in browser) it sends data and everything goes fine. But, if I close the browser window and open again, it stops working.
- Same is the case when two clients connect to it via browser. I want this code to serve multiple clients at a time.

$channel = EM::Channel.new

```
EM.run do
    class App < Sinatra::Base

        get '/' do
            haml :index
        end

    end

    EventMachine::WebSocket.start(:host => '0.0.0.0', :port => 8080) do |ws|
        ws.onopen {
            AMQP.start(:host => "localhost") do |connection|
                $channel = AMQP::Channel.new(connection)
                exchange = $channel.fanout("slant", :auto_delete => false, :durable => true)
                queue        = $channel.queue("my-events", :auto_delete => true, :durable => false)

                queue.bind(exchange, :routing_key => "").subscribe(:ack => true) do |headers, payload|
                    ws.send payload.to_s
                    puts payload
                    $channel.acknowledge(headers.delivery_tag, false)
                end
            end
        }
        ws.onclose { puts "Client disconnected" }
    end
    App.run!({:port => 3000})
end
```

The clients have JS like:

```
$(function(){
  ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");

  ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
    var msg = json_parse(evt.data);

    row = '<tr><td>' + msg.severity + '</td>' + '<td>' + msg.service + '</td>' + '<td>' + msg.description+ '</td>' + '<td>' + msg.server + '</td>'+ '<td>' + msg.source + '</td>' + '<td>' + msg.date + '</td>'  + '<td>' + msg.host_address + '</td>' + '<td>' + msg.additional_info + '</td>' + '<td>' + msg.event_type + '</td>' + '</tr>'
    if ($('#alerts tbody tr:first').length > 0){
      $('#alerts tbody tr:first').before(row);
    } else {
      $('#alerts tbody')append(row);
    }
  };

  ws.onclose = function() {
    ws.send("Leaves the chat");
  };

  ws.onopen = function() {
    ws.send("Join the chat");
  };

});
```

I'm not sure what is going wrong? Looks like there is something fundamentally wrong in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try running EventMachine and the Sinatra app in separate threads